# How to get the current path, keeping the langcode?

Tags: 8, uri

For my button I need to specify the destination path, as my site is multilingual it is imporatnt for me to keep the langcode in the path. So how can I get from

```
 drupal-site/fr/page_1
```

to

```
 drupal-site/fr/page-2 ?
```

By just appending /page-2 I lose my language settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try code:

```
$langcode ='en';
$node_url = $node->getTranslation($langcode)->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
$path = Url::fromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
```

It returns exactly the base route with the langcode